# Asymptotics and little-o notation

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function, taylor-expansion

I always have issues dealing with asymptotic notation...

I am trying to verify the following step:

> $$\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2n} + o(1/n)\right)^n \to e^{-t^2/2}.$$

To change this into $(1-t^2/(2n))^n \to e^{-t^2/2}$, it suffices to show that 
$$\left(1+\frac{o(1/n)}{1-t^2/(2n)}\right)^n \to 1,$$
but I don't see where to go from here. Any hints would be appreciated!

Also apparently the same result holds when replacing $o(1/n)$ with $O(1/n^2)$...

Comment: It suffices to show that $(1+o(1/n))^n \to 1$. Try taking the logarithm and using its series expansion.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Ok, so $n \log(1+o(1/n)) = n o(1/n) \to 0$ which shows your statement. However, I don't see why this is sufficient.

Comment: You wrote that it suffices to show that $(1+o(1/n)/(1-t/(2n)))^n \to 1$. For fixed $t$, $o(1/n)/(1-t/(2n)) = o(1/n)$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Ah, thank you!

Comment: I would gladly upvote it if you were to post your answer to this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2n}\right)\left(1+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)
$$
we can raise both to the $n^{\text{th}}$ power:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2n}\right)^n\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)^n\\
&=e^{-t^2/2}\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{o(1)}\\
&=e^{-t^2/2}\,e^0\\[6pt]
&=e^{-t^2/2}
\end{align}
$$

---

If there is doubt that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)^n=1$, note that since $o\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac{o(1)}n$, we have that for any $\varepsilon\gt0$,
$$
e^{-\varepsilon}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac\varepsilon n\right)^n
\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)^n
\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac\varepsilon n\right)^n=e^\varepsilon
$$
Finish with the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).